# FB.ui not working in IE 10 Compatibility mode

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer

As usual this code works more than fine in all the other browsers and in IE non-compatible mode but in compatible mode the code produces the following error:

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 

     FB.ui(
     {
        method: 'share',
        href: 'http://www.example.com',
     },
     //Here is where the error points to
     function(response) 
     {
        if (response && !response.error_code) 
        {

        } 
     });
```

What exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a misplaced comma in the object definition:

```
FB.ui(
     {
        method: 'share',
        href: 'http://www.example.com', // <-- remove this comma
     },
```